# TypeScript Compiler API - Access to output of compiler stages

Tags: typescript, api, compiler-construction

Is it possible to "bind" custom plugins to various TS stages or call these stages using the TS API? The best way would be to have complete control over the transpillation process.

What I mean is to ideally have a typescript code as a string input, pass it to the parser, get AST tree, analyse/modify it, pass it to TypeChecker, perform custom actions above the checked AST (documentation generation, static code analysis, code optimization, tree shaking, dead code elimination, minification, custom transformations) and emitting it.

As far as I know, it is not a problem to construct AST from string. I also know that following stages are easily customisable, i.e. implementation of custom transforms including the final output emitting.

But I didn't find a way how to type check the custom file (not internally processed and added to the program context), i.e. add the parsed AST to the program (in form of sourceFile) and work with it as if it would be added internally by the program processing.

Is there a way how to let the compiler type check custom AST tree parsed "externally"?